# Glassfish4 Grizzly Not Binding to Port

Tags: java, glassfish, grizzly

We created a cluster of Glassfish4 (two instances). All were working including the load balancing using mod_jk of Apache. Http listeners on port 28080 has `jk-enabled` set to `true`.

After several restarts and deployment of EAR applications, the port was not bound anymore. I checked the server logs and found out that the HTTP listener has started, but Grizzly Framework was not bound to 28080. Other ports are working.

```
[2015-07-24T10:02:37.940+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jts.startup_msg] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.CosTransactions] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1437703356493] [timeMillis: 1437703357940] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]]]

[2015-07-24T10:02:38.111+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1437703356483] [timeMillis: 1437703358111] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 6ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:28181]]]

[2015-07-24T10:02:38.130+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1437703356483] [timeMillis: 1437703358130] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:24848]]]

[2015-07-24T10:02:38.414+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1437703356491] [timeMillis: 1437703358414] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:28080]]

[2015-07-24T10:02:38.419+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1437703356491] [timeMillis: 1437703358419] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:28181]]

[2015-07-24T10:02:38.424+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1437703356491] [timeMillis: 1437703358424] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:24848]]
```

This happens on both Glassfish instances. No SEVERE messages in the log.

Any idea?